# Configure Laravel project to update and delete JSON objects

Tags: laravel, firebase, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase and MySQL as the backend. I can insert data to Firebase using a laravel project. But deleting and updating operations is only valid for MySQL.

I want to make those features active for Firebase also. I am using `Mpociot\Firebase\SyncsWithFirebase` to sync data with Firebase. It is perfectly working for insertion only. I need a solution for that guys.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special that needs to be done. It handles it for you. [let's have a look at that trait](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync/blob/master/src/Mpociot/Firebase/SyncsWithFirebase.php)

```
public static function bootSyncsWithFirebase()
{
    static::created(function ($model) {
        $model->saveToFirebase('set');
    });
    static::updated(function ($model) {
        $model->saveToFirebase('update');
    });
    static::deleted(function ($model) {
        $model->saveToFirebase('delete');
    });
}
```

OK. So it attaches its self to the `create/update/delete` events. What do the rest of the functions do?

```
protected function saveToFirebase($mode)
{
    if (is_null($this->firebaseClient)) {
        $this->firebaseClient = new FirebaseLib(config('services.firebase.database_url'), config('services.firebase.secret'));
    }
    $path = $this->getTable() . '/' . $this->getKey();
    if ($mode === 'set' && $fresh = $this->fresh()) {
        $this->firebaseClient->set($path, $fresh->toArray());
    } elseif ($mode === 'update' && $fresh = $this->fresh()) {
        $this->firebaseClient->update($path, $fresh->toArray());
    } elseif ($mode === 'delete') {
        $this->firebaseClient->delete($path);
    }
}
```

There it is. When a delete occurs through Eloquent/FQB, it's already deleted in Firebase.

Your issue may be that you're not using Eloquent to perform your delete/udpates, so no event is received.

Comment: 'App\EventCal::where('id', 20)->delete();' is the query which I used to delete. It is only deleted from mysql. But not from the firebase. So what would be the query to delete from firebase also?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the first record or you won't have the EventCal model instance.

App\EventCal::where('id', 20)->first()->delete();